# Restrict a model to access only rows with a specific condition?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to use a Django model to access a subset of database rows. Working with a number of legacy databases, I'd rather not create views to the database, if possible.

In short, I'd like to tell my model that there's field `foo` which should always have the value `bar`. This should span any CRUD operation for the table, so that newly created rows would also have `foo`=`bar`. Is there a simple Django way for what I'm trying to achieve?

UPDATE: I want to ensure that this model doesn't write anything to the table where `foo` != `bar`. It must be able to read, modify or delete only those rows where `foo`=`bar`.

Answer (score 1):

For newly created items you can set the `default` value in model definition

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # a lot of fields
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='bar')

    # Set the manager
    objects = BarManager()

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
        self.foo = 'bar'
        super(MyModel, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using)
```

To achieve that `MyModel.objects.all()` should return only rows with `foo=bar` you should implement [your custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers). You can re-define the `get_query_set` method to add filtering.

```
class BarManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(BarManager, self).get_query_set().filter(foo='bar')
```

*Update after @tuomassalo comment*

1) The custom manager will affect all calls to `MyModel.objects.get(id=42)` as this call just proxy a call to `.get_query_set().get(id=42)`. To achieve this you have to set Manager as default manager for model (assign it to `objects` variable).

To use this manager for related lookups (e.g. `another_model_instance.my_model_set.get(id=42)`) you need to set `use_for_related_fields = True` on you `BarManager`. See [Controlling automatic Manager types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/managers/#controlling-automatic-manager-types) in the docs.

2) If you want to enforce `foo=bar` then `default` value is not enough for you. You can either use `pre_save` signal or overwrite the `save` method on your model. Don't forget to call the original save method.

I updated the `MyModel` example above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added a clarification to my question. The `default='bar'` does not *enforce* `foo=bar`. Should I use eg. a pre_save hook for that? Also, does a custom `Manager` affect eg. `.objects.get(id=42)`?

Comment: @tuomassalo I updated my answer with your additional questions